# Agora Cloud Recording [ Web Page Recording ] : Error 404 (no Route matched with those values)

Tags: agora.io

I trying to use new mode recording from Agora [Here](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_webpage_mode?platform=RESTful).

But It doesn't work for me. I always got Error 404 with message ('no Route matched with those values')

Here is my url path

```
'/v1/apps/{appid}/cloud_recording/resourceid/{my-resource-id}/mode/web/start'
```

I already check on [Cloud Recording RESTful API](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/restfulapi) to find pattern for request body but It doesn't said anything about **Web Page Recording**. (Maybe because It's just beta for now)

Here is my start request body that I copy from ***tutorial*** but It doesn't matched with RESTful API

```
const extensionServiceConfig = {
      errorHandlePolicy: "error_abort",
      extensionServices: [{
        serviceName: "web_recorder_service",
        errorHandlePolicy: "error_abort",
        serviceParam: {
          url: "myurl",
          audioProfile: 0,
          videoWidth: 1280,
          videoHeight: 720,
          maxRecordingHour: 2
        }
      }]
    };
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using the 'POST' method and correct app-id with resource-id, because as per the documentation it is a post request.

Comment: can I ask you what's url inside serviceParam is where we can get it from?

Answer (score 0):

The "404 No Routes" error is caused by Cloud Recording not being enabled on your project. To enable cloud recording on your project, you’ll need to click into the *Products & Usage* section of the Agora.io Dashboard and select the project name from the drop-down in the upper left-hand corner, click the *Duration* link below *Cloud Recording*.

[image: screenshot of button to enable could recording]

Here is a step by step guide I wrote: https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708

Also Agora offers a [Postman Collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/6319646/SVSLr9AM?version=latest) that provides a sample body for making a request and if viewed through the Postman app it will generate the JavaScript snippet for you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing {{mode-type}}.

My mistake was that instead of `mix` I was using `composite` as the selected mode.

Correct url in that case:

```
https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/{{APPID}}/cloud_recording/resourceid/{{resourceId}}/mode/mix/start
```

[Documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/reference/rest-api/start)

> One of the following three recording modes: Individual recording
> (individual): Records the audio and video of each user ID in separate
> files. Composite recording (mix): (Default) Records the audio and
> video of multiple user IDs in a single file. Web page recording (web):
> Records the content and audio on a specified web page in a single
> file.